# T-Sql Sum Positive and Negative Float Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sum

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 
        ITM.CODE AS ITMCODE,
        CASE 
           WHEN IOCODE IN (1,2) THEN AMOUNT 
           ELSE AMOUNT * -1 
        END AS AMOUNT
    FROM 
        ITEMLINE ITL, ITEMS ITM 
    WHERE 
        ITL.ITEMREF = ITM.LOGICALREF 
        AND ITM.CODE = '123'
)
SELECT 
    ITMCODE, SUM(AMOUNT)  
FROM 
    CTE 
GROUP BY 
    ITMCODE
```

There are five rows returned from the CTE, and amount is of type `float`. Sum function returns 2,27373675443232E-13. if i don't use Amount * -1 there is no problem, returned value is normal. what causes this? This returns from a view and i can't alter the view it is forbidden, i must fix the values. Values that five rows are 5,6,7,8,9. Thanks.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

First, your query is too complicated.  Just do:

```
SELECT ITM.CODE AS ITMCODE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN IOCODE IN (1, 2) THEN AMOUNT ELSE AMOUNT * -1 
           END) AS AMOUNT
FROM ITEMLINE ITL JOIN
     ITEMS ITM 
     ON ITL.ITEMREF = ITM.LOGICALREF 
WHERE ITM.CODE = '123'
GROUP BY ITM.CODE;
```

Second, this is the nature of floating point numbers.  You should be storing amounts as `decimal`/`numeric`, fixed point numbers.

You should be able to get what you want by converting to the appropriate type:

```
SELECT ITM.CODE AS ITMCODE,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 2),  -- or whatever
               SUM(CASE WHEN IOCODE IN (1, 2) THEN AMOUNT ELSE AMOUNT * -1 
                   END)
              ) AS AMOUNT
FROM ITEMLINE ITL JOIN
     ITEMS ITM 
     ON ITL.ITEMREF = ITM.LOGICALREF 
WHERE ITM.CODE = '123'
GROUP BY ITM.CODE;
```

However, I would recommend that you fix the data in your table to store amounts in a manner more suitable for monetary amounts, so:

```
alter table itemline alter column amount decimal(12, 4);  -- or whatever
```

Comment: Problem is not about query. Query is just an example. When i update rows manuel, for examle UPDATE ITEMLINE SET AMOUNT = 5 WHERE REF = 1, UPDATE ITEMLINE SET AMOUNT = 6 WHERE REF = 2.. There is no problem. There are problem about values. I need to fix them.